# How to configure Camel's jackson XmlMapper?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, apache-camel

I have a SpringBoot application, using Camel for routing.
For configuring jackson xmlMapper, I have the following spring bean:

```
@Bean
public XmlMapper xmlMapper() {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
    return xmlMapper;
}
```

And I want Camel to use this mapper when unmarshalling received POJOs as following:

```
from("direct:myRoute")
     .marshal().jacksonxml()
     .inOnly("activemq:outputQueue");
```

But it doesn't work this way: null fields are present in marshalled xml.
Camel documentation offers to use JacksonXMLDataFormat as following:

```
JacksonXMLDataFormat format = new JacksonXMLDataFormat();
format.setInclude("NON_NULL");
from("direct:myRoute")
     .marshal(format)
     .inOnly("activemq:outputQueue");
```

It works, but I have to specify dataFormat each time I marshal something, and it gets trickier with unmarshalling.

Is there a unified way to configure Camel's xmlMapper?

Comment: Do you have an answer yet?

Comment: did yout tried `@Primary` annotation on the method?